# Get pop Up on button click in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to Pop Up menu on button click which contains data for particular user. I have written code for component in js file as below:

```
Object.keys(user).map(function (key,index){
          console.log(user[key].pk);
          return(
          <tr>
            <td>
              {user[key].pk}
            </td>
            <td>
              {user[key].fields.username}3
            </td>
            <td>
              {user[key].fields.email}
            </td>
            <td style={{align:"center"}}>
            <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={}><Glyphicon glyph="tag" /></Button>

            </td>
            <td>
            <Button bsStyle="danger"><Glyphicon glyph="remove" /></Button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          )
```

So please guide me, What i need to do for solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call a function `onClick` and pass the `key and pk`(assuming pk to be a unique identifier) to it. After that you can open the menu and display the user details based on key and pk

```
openPopupMenu = (key, pk) => {
    this.setState({key, id: pk});
    //open popup menu from here and supply these identifiers
}

<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={() => this.openPopupMenu(key, user[key].pk)}><Glyphicon glyph="tag" /></Button>
```

Comment: Thank You sir. But I have get data of user. But please send me code for pop up. i have added this much:
openPopupMenu(key, pk) {
    this.setState({key, id: pk});
    alert("hiii in pop up menu "+user[key].pk+"  "+user[key].fields.username+"   "+user[key].fields.email+"  "+user[key].fields.password);
}

Comment: Great_DR, There are lots of resources available which show you how to show a popup. I am sure you can find one of them

Comment: Ok. Thank You so much Sir